# The easiest way to upload a file to PostgreSQL with Express and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am building an application that is a news portal, and this kind of application needs to upload files in its stories. I am using PostgreSQL as the database to store all the information from the portal.

I wanted to know how to upload files received by post in express to my PostgreSQL db, I searched a lot on the internet and did not find anything very simple.

So how can I do this in a simple and effective way, in a way that I can later serve this file in a url?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "production": "pm2 start index.js --name knowledge-backend"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "busboy": "^1.6.0",
    "consign": "0.1.6",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "jwt-simple": "0.5.1",
    "knex": "0.21.1",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-schedule": "1.3.0",
    "passport": "0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.0",
    "pg": "8.0.3",
    "pm2": "3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "1.18.4"
  }
}
```

And here's what I've tried:

```
const busboy = require('busboy')

module.exports = app => {
    const save = (req, res) => {
        try {
            let bb = busboy({
                headers: req.headers,
                defCharset: "utf8"
            });
            let fields = {};
            bb.on("field", (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) => {
                console.log(fieldname, val);
                fields[fieldname] = val;
            });
            bb.on("file", (fieldname, fileStream, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
                console.log('File captured')
            });
            res.status(200).send()
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("file upload catch", err);
        }
    }
}
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.route('/files')
        .post(app.api.file.save)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this file, it has three functions, one to save, one to get a file by id, and one to remove a file by id:

```
const busboy = require('busboy')
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = app => {
    const save = (req, res) => {
        const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        bb.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
            const saveTo = path.join(os.tmpdir(), String(filename.filename));
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo)).on('close', function () {
                fs.readFile(saveTo, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    app.db('files').insert({ name: filename, data: data })
                        .returning('id')
                        .then(id => {
                            console.log('https://localhost:3000/files/' + id);
                            fs.unlink(saveTo, function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log('Arquivo removido com sucesso!');
                            });
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            console.error(err);
                        });
                });
            });
        });
        bb.on('finish', function () {
            console.log('Upload complete');
            res.status(200).send("That's all folks!");
        });
        return req.pipe(bb);
    };

    const getById = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;

        app.db('files')
            .select('data')
            .where({ id })
            .first()
            .then((result) => {
                const fileData = result.data;
                res.contentType('application/octet-stream');
                res.send(fileData);
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
    }

    const remove = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;

        app.db('files')
            .where({ id })
            .first().del()
            .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
            .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
    }

    return { save, getById, remove }
}
```

This file is a Node.js module that contains functions to handle uploading files to PostgreSQL using Express. It defines three functions: save, getById and remove, which are exported for use in other parts of the code and you can link these functions directly into your routes:

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.route('/files')
        .post(app.api.file.save)

    app.route('/files/:id')
        .get(app.api.file.getById)
        .delete(app.api.file.remove)
}
```

The save function is using the busboy library (as it was already being used) to parse the HTTP request and extract the data from the file, it then saves the file temporarily on the operating system using the fs module of Node.js, the temporary path of the file is obtained using the path and os modules, the contents of the file are read from the file system and then inserted into the PostgreSQL database using the insert function of knex.js. After insertion into the database the temporary file is removed using the unlink function of the fs module.

The getById function is responsible for getting a file from the database by its ID, but it can be modified to get a file by filename if preferred. It takes the ID as a parameter in the URL of the request and performs a database query to retrieve the contents of the file. The content is returned as the request response with the Content-Type header set to application/octet-stream, indicating that the content is a byte stream.

The remove function is responsible for deleting a file from the database by its ID. It takes the ID as a parameter in the request URL and performs a delete operation on the database.